# How skip vmart dataabse loading?

Tags: vertica

I am running docker `vertica/vertica-ce` image. But during start up it loads `VMart` database as example. I do not want this. Is there a way to disable this?

I have tried to set

- `export WITH_VMART=false`
- `export VMART_LOAD_DATA=n`

But it loads data anyway :'(

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

1. create dummy bash file `vmart-loading-skipper.sh`
2. add to dockerfile: `ADD vmart-loading-skipper.sh /somepath/vmart-loading-skipper.sh`
3. add to dockerfile: `ENV VMART_ETL_SCRIPT=${HOME}/vmart-loading-skipper.sh`

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new image with the vmart loading removed from the entrypoint script.

Here is a sample Dockerfile:

```
FROM vertica/vertica-ce:latest
RUN sed -i '/VMART_ETL_SCRIPT/d' /home/dbadmin/docker-entrypoint.sh
```

Then build this like you would any other docker image.

```
$ docker build -t vertica-ce-novmart .
```